# AdSense balance not updating despite estimated earnings going up

Tags: google-adsense

I have installed adsense on my website a bit over a month ago. During the first few days estimated earnings started to update my overall balance (increasing it). My balance was at ca.80usd from having previously earned ad money from a youtube account.

Now, a month later, **despite seeing estimated earnings and clicks every day, my balance remains at ~96usd and hasn't budged since.** My estimated earnings over this time is at 66usd. Added on to my balance it should be over 100usd (the min threshhold for being paid out).

Several years ago I have already gotten paid out once before thanks to the youtube earnings. So the bank account that is linked is correct and works. Furthermore, my account is shown as beeing approved (and confirmed).

I have read through the google help documentation, but couldn't see a reason for my balance not updating. I contacted google using their form, but ofcourse they don't respond.

Has anyone had this problem and if so did you manage to get paid by google and how?

Comment: Wait for [finalized earnings](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/32852?hl=en) reports.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, you are earning Adsense from your site and from a Youtube channel. Youtube earnings are handled separately, and will only compute in your balance after the finalized earnings.

Comment: Then I should see my earnings updated at the latest at the end of this month?! I'll report back when that happens or if it doesn't. Thanks for your help thus far.